# Formatting HTML within VBA

Tags: html, vba

I'm currently facing issues with putting HTML into VBA to send an e-mail. The formatting isn't coming out the way I want and I've been playing around with it.

The first part of my question is to get the font size to show up Outlook to what the code states. If the font size is 22, the size is being displayed in Outlook as 16.5 (the first line).

If the font size is supposed to be set to 11, the size is being displayed as 8.5.

I have the following questions for the table: 
The font is showing up as Times New Roman size 12 instead of Calibri size 11. Also, all of the "Column" and "Top Line" are not aligned to the top.

Is the syntax wrong?

```
.HTMLBody = "<html><center><p style='font-family:calibri;font-size:22'>" & "***<u>TEXT AT TOP</u> ***" & "</center></p>" & "<br>" & "<br>" & _
        "<p style='font-family:calibri;font-size:11'>" & "Good afternoon," & "</p>" & "<br>" & _
        "<p style='font-family:calibri;font-size:11'>" & "Attached please find your ... <strong> Please be advised.....</strong>" & "</p>" & _
         "<table><tr><td style='font-family:Calibri:align = top:font-size:11'>Column 1:</td><td style='font-family:Calibri'>Top Line</td></tr>" & "<br>" & _
        "<tr><td style='font-family:Calibri:align = top:font-size:11'>Column 2</td><td style='font-family:Calibri:align = top:font-size:11'>Top Line Row 2 <br> More text</tr></td>" & "<br>" & _
        "<tr><td></td><td style='font-family:Calibri:align = top:font-size:11'>Top Line Row 3 <br> More text </tr></td>" & "<br>" & _
        "<tr><td style='font-family:Calibri:align = top:font-size:11'>Column 3</td><td style='font-family:Calibri:align = top:font-size:11'>Top Line Row 4:</tr></td></table>" & "<br>" & _
        "<p style='font-family:calibri:font-size:11'>" & "Should you have any questions, or require any additional information, please do not hesitate to contact me anytime.  Thank you!" & "</p>" & "<br>" & _
        "<p style='font-family:calibri:font-size:11'>" & "Best regards," & "</p>" & _
         "<table><tr><td style='font-family:Calibri:font-size:12'><strong>Size 12 text</strong> | text <br> text </tr></td>" & _
         "<tr><td style='font-family:Calibri:font-size:12><strong>Name</strong></tr></td><table>"                   .Display
```

Thank you!

Comment: Hold on here, *no one* ever came up with a COM type library that exposes functionality for generating correct HTML markup using objects? Getting ideas... #SeeANeed #FillANeed

Comment: Save yourself some grief, put the formatted HTML in a cell, then get the value of that cell for the HTMLBody. Typing it in VBE is not a lot of fun.

Answer (score 2):

You have tones of errors in your HTML:

- You're missing `<body>`.
- You need to specify the unit for your font size. Something like `22pt` or `22px`.
- You used colons `:` instead of semicolons `;` in many places.
- `align=top` is not CSS property, so move it out of `style`.
- You cannot have `<br>` between your cells and rows.
- `</td>` must come after `</tr>`, not before.
- You didn't close your second table and your `<html>`.

Here is cleaned HTML:

```
"<html><body><center><p style='font-family:calibri;font-size:22px;'>" & _
"***<u>TEXT AT TOP</u> ***</center></p><br><br>" & _
"<p style='font-family:calibri;font-size:11px;'>" & _
"Good afternoon,</p><br>" & _
"<p style='font-family:calibri;font-size:11px;'>" & _
"Attached please find your ... <strong> Please be advised.....</strong></p>" & _
"<table><tr><td style='font-family:Calibri;font-size:11px;' align='top'>Column 1:</td>" & _
"<td style='font-family:Calibri;'>Top Line</td></tr>" & _
"<tr><td style='font-family:Calibri;font-size:11px;' align='top'>Column 2</td>" & _
"<td style='font-family:Calibri;font-size:11px;' align='top'>Top Line Row 2 <br> More text</td></tr>" & _
"<tr><td></td><td style='font-family:Calibri;font-size:11px;' align='top'>Top Line Row 3 <br> More text </td></tr>" & _
"<tr><td style='font-family:Calibri;font-size:11px' align='top'>Column 3</td>" & _
"<td style='font-family:Calibri;font-size:11px;' align='top'>Top Line Row 4:</td></tr></table><br>" & _
"<p style='font-family:calibri;font-size:11px;'>Should you have any questions, or require any additional information, please do not hesitate to contact me anytime.  Thank you!</p><br>" & _
"<p style='font-family:calibri;font-size:11px;'>Best regards,</p>" & _
"<table><tr><td style='font-family:Calibri;font-size:12px;'><strong>Size 12 text</strong> | text <br> text </td></tr>" & _
"<tr><td style='font-family:Calibri;font-size:12px;><strong>Name</strong></td></tr></table></body></html>"
```